# Unable to get item by slug instead of id in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to make my URL's a bit user friendly but I'm unable.

I have added in my `RouteServiceProvider` this

```
Route::bind('items_route', function ($value) {         
   return \App\Item::where('alias', $value)->firstOrFail();  
});
```

This is my `route.php`

```
Route::get('item/{item}', 'ItemController@show')->name('item.show');
```

The button in my view

```
{!! HTML::linkRoute('item.show', 'View', array($item->alias)) !!}
```

And the controller

```
public function show( Item $items_route )
{
    $reviews = Review::where('item_id', $items_route->id)->where('approved', 1)->get();
    $item = Item::with('taggs')->find($items_route->id);
        $additionAds = Item::with('taggs')->where('id', '!=', $items_route->id)->get();
    if($item) {
        $item->views = (int) $item->views +1;
        $item->save();
    }

    $category = Category::find($item->category_id);
    if($category->parent_id == 0) {

         $ids = Category::select('id')->where('parent_id', $item->category_id)->where('parent_id','!=',0)->get();
         $array = array();

         foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $array[] = (int) $id->id;
         }
         $items = Item::select('*')->whereIn('category_id',$array)->whereNotIn('id', [$item->id])->get();

    } else {
        $items =  Item::select('*')->where('category_id' ,$item->category_id)->whereNotIn('id', [$item->id])->get();
    } 

    $item_images = Item_Images::where('item_id',$items_route->id)->get();

    $defaultCountry = DB::table('items')
                ->leftJoin('countries', 'items.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')
                ->where('items.id', $items_route->id)
                ->select('items.*', 'countries.*')
                ->first();
    return view('item', compact('item','items','item_images','defaultCountry', 'additionAds', 'reviews'));
}
```

The error is

> ErrorException in ItemController.php line 40:
>   Trying to get property of non-object

Line 40 is where making query for Category `$category = Category::find($item->category_id);`. The error appears because the `$item` is null.

Can anyone tell whats going on here? Why I can't get the item and all attributes from the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because there is no Item in the DB with `ID = $items_route->id`, so this code will return `null`:

```
Item::with('taggs')->find($items_route->id);
```

So, you need to check results:

```
if (is_null($item)) {
    // Do some stuff.
} else {
    // Item is not found.
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm sure that the item is existing. I can't understand why is not find. Is it because `$items_route` contain `alias` eg. slug instead of ID?

Comment: @Ivan yes, `find()` method uses `id`, so you need to do something like `Item::with('taggs')->where('slug', $slug)->first()` instead.

Comment: Still same error. I've checked `$items_route` with `dd($items_route)` and it's empty too.

Comment: I've found the problem. The problem was that in my route.php I have `get('item/{item}'...`, it should be `get('item/{items_route}'` because in router I expecting `$items_route`. Once I've changed it is works. Thanks for the `Item::with('taggs')->where('slug', $slug)->first()` too.